# Getting NullPointerException in getDrawable method on Glide

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, imageview, android-glide

I have an imageview and I'll like to get the Bitmap of it...

Here is my code:

Setting the imageview:

```
ImageView imageView;
imageView =  findViewById(R.id.image_wallpaper);
Glide.with(this).load(current_image.getImageURL()).into(imageView);
```

Getting the bitmap:

```
setButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();

        imageView.invalidate();  // I get the crash with or without that line
        Bitmap mBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();  // CRASH HERE

        // more things using the mBitmap

    }
});
```

The crash log:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.Bitmap android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.getBitmap()' on a null object reference
com.XXXX.XXXXXXX.ImageActivity$4.onClick (ImageActivity.java:170)
android.view.View.performClick (View.java:5246)
android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:21200)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:145)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6946)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1404)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

I'm using last version of Glide:

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'                   // glide
```

This crash log comes from Firebase Crashlytics, a lot of users get that error, but I'm unable to reproduce it on my devices.

What's the problem? How can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/60206330/11158194 may be it's helpful for you to get bitmap of any view.

Comment: Have you initalized this imageView?

Comment: Hey check my answer it my helps you

Answer (score 1):

There is a method in the Glide Library in which you can get bitmap, you can use that method to get bitmap and set into Imageview.

You can also use resource drawable in place of the "imagepath".

```
Glide.with(context)
        .asBitmap()
        .placeholder(placeholder)
        .error(placeholder)
        .load(
            "imagepath"
        )
        .into(object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
            override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
                // here you will get Bitmap file and you can use it to set on image view.
                image.setImageBitmap(resource)
            }

            override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {
                // this is called when imageView is cleared on lifecycle call or for some other reason.
                // if you are referencing the bitmap somewhere else too other than this imageView clear it here as you can no longer have the bitmap.              
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please post your imageView initialization ? 
If not done you need to initialize it first :

```
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.myimageViewId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add dependency :

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

and write below code snippet:

```
                             try {
                                Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                                        .load(YOUR_IMAGE_URL)
                                        .asBitmap()
                                        .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                                                Uri bmpUri = Common.getLocalBitmapUri(resource, context);
                                    your_image_view.setImageBitmap(resource);

                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void onLoadFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable) {
                                                super.onLoadFailed(e, errorDrawable);
                                            }
                                        });
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.getStackTrace();
                            }
```

Hope this may helps you